# R: bug in apply()?

Tags: r, apply

I'm getting some bizarre behavior when using apply(). I'm trying to create a logical vector to indicate whether a given column is a dummy variable (only 0 and 1 values). Having missing values should still counts as a dummy, so long as all non-NA values are 0 or 1.

If the dataframe in question contains only numeric values, my code works fine.
BUT, if the data frame also contains a string column, the function no longer ignores NA values, even when examining the numeric columns which previously worked.

Example:

```
x1 = c(1,0,1,NA)
x2 = c(1,1,0,1)
x3 = c(1,2,3,4)
x4 = c('a','b','c','d')
dat1 = data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
dat2 = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
isdum1 = apply(dat1,2,function(x) {all(x %in% c(0:1,NA))})
isdum2 = apply(dat2,2,function(x) {all(x %in% c(0:1,NA))})

isdum1   # works fine
   x1    x2    x3 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
isdum2   # wtf?
   x1    x2    x3    x4 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: `apply` should be used with `array`-like objects. For `data.frames`, if you want to apply a function to each column, use `lapply` (or `vapply`).

Comment: Or as gold member, [@DavidArenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg), warns new useRs: *1. if you are working with data.frames, forget there is a function called apply- whatever you do - don't use it. Especially with a margin of 1 (the only good usecase for this function is to operate over matrix columns- margin of 2).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `apply` converts data frame to matrix and matrix can hold only one type of value.

See,

```
apply(dat1, 2, class)
#    x1        x2        x3 
#"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 

apply(dat2, 2, class)
#      x1          x2          x3          x4 
#"character" "character" "character" "character"
```

So for first column it actually checks

```
all(c("1", "0", "1", "NA") %in% c(0:1,NA))
#[1] FALSE
```

hence, the answer.

You could instead use `sapply` which also operates column-wise without changing the class.

```
sapply(dat1, function(x) {all(x %in% c(0:1,NA))})
#   x1    x2    x3 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE 

sapply(dat2, function(x) {all(x %in% c(0:1,NA))})
#   x1    x2    x3    x4 
# TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: I see, brilliant!